# change header top banner content on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, conditional-statements, customization

I have a static top banner inside my header.php file  build like this :

```
<div class="row-fluid top-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-overlay"></div>
        <?php 
        $logo = of_get_option('logo', '' );
        if ( !empty( $logo ) ) { ?>
            <a class="brand brand-image" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><h1><?php if(!of_get_option('disable_description')){ ?><small><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></small><?php } ?></h1></a>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <a class="brand brand-text" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><h1><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?><?php if(!of_get_option('disable_description')){ ?><small><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></small><?php } ?></h1></a>
        <?php } 
        if(of_get_option('disable_description')){ $top_banner_fix = 'style="top:15px;"'; }else{ $top_banner_fix = ''; }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to change top-banner div content on a specific page, in my case the contact page which is created from the dashboard is not a template page.

So, I'm thinking to use the conditional tag :`<?php is_page($page); ?>`

The problem is that I'm not sure how to use this function. Is it possible to just add some markup inside the div and it will overwrite the existing one ?

Can you please give me some indications on how can I do this ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_page is a boolean function, so it's as easy as a new `if else` clause:

```
<div class="row-fluid top-banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-overlay"></div>
        <?php 
        $logo = of_get_option('logo', '' );
        if (is_page($contactPage)) { 
            /*PUT STATIC CONTENT HERE*/
        } else if ( !empty( $logo ) ) { ?>
            <a class="brand brand-image" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"><h1><?php if(!of_get_option('disable_description')){ ?><small><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></small><?php } ?></h1></a>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <a class="brand brand-text" href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><h1><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?><?php if(!of_get_option('disable_description')){ ?><small><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></small><?php } ?></h1></a>
        <?php } 
        if(of_get_option('disable_description')){ $top_banner_fix = 'style="top:15px;"'; }
        else{ $top_banner_fix = ''; }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

For `$contactpage`: when you are logged in into your Wordpress admin site, go to the frontend. Then go to the contact page (the one you want to have this new content on). Click on edit in the top banner. Look at the link. (You can also get there via the dashboard).

The link will look a bit like this: `post.php?post=280&action=edit`
That number, 280 in this case, is the ID of the page. You can use that for `$contactPage`:

```
if (is_page(280)) { /*...*/ }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For different banner on all pages and posts you can use [Attachment Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments/) and then have to create instance for that in function.php file. then you can see that attachment metabox in all pages and post form page in admin panel.